# Exchange expression in VIM

Tags: regex, vim

Suppose I have code like `(<expression1>/<expression2>)`

For example,

```
(dog/cat)
(Washington/London)
```

how can I exchange expression1 and expression2 in ***vim*** quickly. The expected result is to be following:

```
(cat/dog)
(London/Washington)
```

All answers are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If *fast* means with a single keystroke, then use a *mapping*, for example to the `q` key:

```
:map q F(ldf/f)pr)F)r/
```

Place cursor anywhere between the parentheses and press `q`. What this does:

- `F(l` Finds opening `(` and moves to start of first word
- `df/` Deletes up to and including `/`
- `f)p` Finds `)` and pastes the deleted word (now looks like `(cat)dog/`)
- `r)` Replaces the inserted `/` with a `)`
- `F)r/` Goes back to the `)` and replaces it with `/`

Limitations: words must not contain `/`, `(` or `)`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [vim-exchange](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-exchange) plugin

```
:%norm lcxiwww.
```

How it works? To exchange two words you can select the first one with `cxiw`, "cx" is part of the plugin mappings, "iw" is a vim text-object that means "inner word". then we jump to the next word and press "." (dot)

Breaking down the suggested command

```
:%normal ................ apply on the whole file "%" in normal mode
l ....................... skip the first (
cxiw .................... mark the first word to exchange
ww ...................... jump to the second word
```

I guess is not necessary to create any mappings due the fact that vim-exchange is very intuitive.